# How to pass multiple #div id in the ajax for advanced search feature

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**index.php**

```
$('#search1, #search2').change(function() {
 var value = $(this).val();
 $.ajax({
   type:"post",
   url:"php/search.php",
   data:'task1='+value,
   success: function(response){
    $('#result').html(response);
   }
  });
});

<select id="search1" name="task1">....</select>
<select id="search2" name="task2">...</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

**search.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['task1']) ? $_POST['task1'] : false) {
   $option = isset($_POST['task1']) ? $_POST['task1'] : false;
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <columnName>='$option'";
   if (isset($_POST['task2']) ? $_POST['task2'] : false) {
    $pilihan = isset($_POST['task2']) ? $_POST['task2'] : false;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <columnName>='$option' and <columnName>='$pilihan'";
   }
}
```

My question is how can i pass multiple #div into one ajax. In other word, how to make sure that #search2 and #task2 can pass and query their process same as #search1 and #task1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can get the name of select tag while change the options and make new variable, then pass that too data.

***index.php***

```
$('#search1, #search2').change(function() {
 var value1 = $(#search1).val();
 var value2 = $(#search2).val();
 var str = 'task1='+value1+'task2='+value2;
 $.ajax({
   type:"GET",
   url:"php/search.php",
   data: str,
   success: function(response){
    $('#result').html(response);
   }
  });
});

<select id="search1" name="task1">....</select>
<select id="search2" name="task2">...</select>

<div id="result"></div>
```

***search.php***

```
$option = false;
if (isset($_GET['task1'])) {
   $option = $_GET['task1'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <columnName>='$option'";
}
if (isset($_GET['task2']) {
    if (isset($_GET['task1'])) {
       $option = $_GET['task1'];
    }
    $pilihan = $_GET['task2'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE <columnName>='$option' and <columnName>='$pilihan'";
}
```

I hope this will help to achieve your goal

Comment: thanks a lot now i can pass the value of each <select> name. can you help  me with the php and query on how to filter each "search column" so that the more I choose on the <select> function, it will filter more on the result. In other word, if I only filter one <select> function, it will give the result based on the selected column only

Comment: if i select "task1" it will show a set of result of the #search1 div. but if i select both "task1" and "task2" it will filter more the result based on the selection. Can you help me?

Comment: you are welcome :), updated the answer if need more help ask separate question